# How to split a 2D Array into Multiple 2D Arrays depending on column values Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, decision-tree

I'm trying to write a code that makes a decision tree from scratch. At one point I need to split my 2D array (filled) with data into multiple 2D arrays, and then split those arrays into even more arrays. So for example, If i have data like this in my 2D array

```
sunny, hot, high, weak, no
sunny, hot, high, strong, no
overcast, hot, high, weak, yes
rain, mild, high, weak, yes
rain,cool, normal, weak, yes
rain, cool, normal, strong, no
overcast, cool, normal, strong, yes
sunny, mild, high, weak, no
sunny, cool, normal, weak, yes
rain, mild, normal, weak, yes
sunny, mild, normal, strong, yes
overcast, mild, high, strong, yes
overcast, hot, normal, weak, yes
rain, mild, high, strong, no
```

So I'll have a code that will calculate the best column to split on, and then i want it to split it. So for example, let's say i want to split based on the values of the first column. The result will be three subsets

```
sunny                             rain                           overcast

sunny, hot, high, weak, no        rain, mild, high, weak, yes    overcast, hot, high, weak, yes
sunny, hot, high, strong, no      rain,cool, normal, weak, yes   overcast, cool, normal, strong, yes
sunny, mild, high, weak, no       rain, cool, normal, strong, no overcast, mild, high, strong, yes
sunny, cool, normal, weak, yes    rain, mild, normal, weak, yes  overcast, hot, normal, weak, yes
sunny, mild, normal, strong, yes  rain, mild, high, strong, no
```

And then i want to use the same algorithm, find the best value to split on, and split again, so for example, let's say i want to to split the sunny array again based on the values of the fourth column. The result this time will be two subsets

```
weak                                 strong

sunny, hot, high, weak, no           sunny, hot, high, strong, no
sunny, mild, high, weak, no          sunny, mild, normal, strong, yes
sunny, cool, normal, weak, yes
```

I know the logic should be something like this

```
split(featureToSplitOn, data)
int bestColumn=findBestColumnToSplitOn();
for every value in best column 
split(value,subset);
```

But I honestly have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Define "best column to split on". Describing your requirement can really help you realize how to code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think splitting is the correct term to use. When I look at your examples it looks like you would rather want to group your data. The best and easiest way to group elements in collections in java is  with the help of streams. Here are some examples that might serve as a starting point for you:

```
String[][] myArray = {  {"sunny", "hot", "high", "weak", "no"},
                        {"sunny", "hot", "high", "strong", "no"},
                        {"overcast", "hot", "high", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"rain", "mild", "high", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"rain", "cool", "normal", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"rain", "cool", "normal", "strong", "no"},
                        {"overcast", "cool", "normal", "strong", "yes"},
                        {"sunny", "mild", "high", "weak", "no"},
                        {"sunny", "cool", "normal", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"rain", "mild", "normal", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"sunny", "mild", "normal", "strong", "yes"},
                        {"overcast", "mild", "high", "strong", "yes"},
                        {"overcast", "hot", "normal", "weak", "yes"},
                        {"rain", "mild", "high", "strong", "no"}
                    };
Map<String,List<String[]>> mapByfirstColumn = Arrays.stream(myArray).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e[0]));
mapByfirstColumn.forEach((key, val)-> {
    System.out.println(key);
    val.forEach(arr -> {System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));});            
});
```

The output ov the above code is:

```
rain
[rain, mild, high, weak, yes]
[rain, cool, normal, weak, yes]
[rain, cool, normal, strong, no]
[rain, mild, normal, weak, yes]
[rain, mild, high, strong, no]
overcast
[overcast, hot, high, weak, yes]
[overcast, cool, normal, strong, yes]
[overcast, mild, high, strong, yes]
[overcast, hot, normal, weak, yes]
sunny
[sunny, hot, high, weak, no]
[sunny, hot, high, strong, no]
[sunny, mild, high, weak, no]
[sunny, cool, normal, weak, yes]
[sunny, mild, normal, strong, yes]
```

You can achieve the multilevel grouping by just applying a grouping to the previous groups as below

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<String[]>>> mapByFirstThen3rd = Arrays.stream(myArray)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e[0],Collectors.groupingBy(e->e[3])));

mapByFirstThen3rd.forEach((outerKey, map)-> {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(outerKey);
    map.forEach((innerKey, val) ->{
        System.out.println(innerKey);
        val.forEach(arr -> {System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));});      
    });            
});
```

which will output something like

```
rain
strong
[rain, cool, normal, strong, no]
[rain, mild, high, strong, no]
weak
[rain, mild, high, weak, yes]
[rain, cool, normal, weak, yes]
[rain, mild, normal, weak, yes]

overcast
strong
[overcast, cool, normal, strong, yes]
[overcast, mild, high, strong, yes]
weak
[overcast, hot, high, weak, yes]
[overcast, hot, normal, weak, yes]

sunny
strong
[sunny, hot, high, strong, no]
[sunny, mild, normal, strong, yes]
weak
[sunny, hot, high, weak, no]
[sunny, mild, high, weak, no]
[sunny, cool, normal, weak, yes]
```